# sound clips get cut off in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, executable-jar

I'm working on a 2D Game in Java and have the problem that the game's sounds will get cut off after playing for a couple of milliseconds when I run the game from an executable Jar file.
The sounds play correctly when I run the game from eclipse.

I load the sound files (.wav) like this:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("sounds/sound.wav"));
AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
int size = (int) (af.getFrameSize() * ais.getFrameLength());
byte[] audio = new byte[size];
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af, size);
ais.read(audio, 0, size);
sound= (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
sound.open(af, audio, 0, size);
```

I play the sounds later in the game like this:

```
public void playClip(final Clip clip, final int loop){
    Runnable soundPlayer = new Runnable() {
        Clip sound = clip;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sound.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                sound.loop(loop);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(soundPlayer).start();
}
```

Do you have any idea why the program behaves like that and how to fix that problem?
Thanks in advance for your help!